# Flutter Stripe sofort, ideal payment

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I create a payment through sofort, ideal, pass the specified parameters and every time I get an error-
Error from Stripe: Invalid Payment Intent client secret: src_client_secret_**********************

```
final paymentIntent = await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
data: PaymentMethodParams.sofort(
paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodDataSofort(country: 'de'),
),
);
```

clientSecret-the key is generated without any problems

payment by card is fine

What am I doing wrong?

I am using the latest versions of the libraries: flutter_stripe: ^7.0.0

I looked through all the information in the library and couldn't find anything

Comment: From the error, `Invalid Payment Intent client secret: src_client_secret_`, it looks like the `client_secret` passed on the confirmation call is not the Payment Intent’s client secret. You'd need to use the client secret of the Payment Intent: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret. From looking at this, https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_stripe/latest/flutter_stripe/Stripe/confirmPayment.html your code snippet is generally appears to be correct but `src_client_secret` is not the Payment Intent’s client secret.

Comment: Your tip is correct, but the secret key you showed as an example refers to card payment. and for other payments of payment types it has a different type. And that's why I have this error